# Pycharm Python "can't open file","[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run a simple Hello World code in pycharm using Python. I have moved the file to another folder. So, I have changed the interpreter location I am getting the following error. This problem has nothing to do with interpreter as you can see in the second image, the interpreter is the correct one and I am able to run it from command prompt.

> C:\Users\bitan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/Python/Free Code Camp/Learning': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

> Process finished with exit code 2"

[image: Error Image]
[image: Interpreter Location Change]

I am new to Pycharm/Python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your script is named `Learning.py`, not just `Learning` - but I don't know where Pycharm is getting that command line from, so I don't know exactly what you need to change.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks a lot Jason, that solved my problem. If anyone else face the same issue, I am adding how to change it. On the top right, click on edit configuration -> Change Script Path.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots, and especially not low-contrast screen shots, which are hard for some users to read.

Comment: ANSWER: PyCharm > select "Run" menu > select "Edit Configurations" menu option > choose configuration to edit > the value of the "Script Path" field needs to be a valid path to a *.py file on your OS > click OK

Answer (score -3):

go to `cmd prompt` and type `cd <path/of/your/python/file>`

then type `python3 file_name.py`

hope it works. if you get an error comment it.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I am not able to use it from the Pycharm.

Comment: -1 because the the answer doesn't match the question. (I was going to take the -1 back when I realized the initial question was ambiguous, but I didn't realize that fast enough and it's now locked in until you edit this so... may as well fix it?)